# Pandas Regex: Separate name from string that starts with word or start of string, and ends in certain words

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas series that contains rows of share names amongst other details:

```
Netflix DIVIDEND
Apple Inc (All Sessions) COMM
Intel Corporation CONS
Correction Netflix Section 31 Fee
```

I'm trying to use a regex to retrieve the stock name, which I did with this look ahead:

```
transactions_df["Share Name"] = transactions_df["MarketName"].str.extract(r"(^.*?(?=DIVIDEND|\(All|CONS|COMM|Section))")
```

The only thing I'm having trouble with is the row `Correction Netflix Section 31 Fee`, where my regex is getting the sharename as `Correction Netflix`. I don't want the word "Correction".

I need my regular expression to check for either the start of the string, OR the word "Correction ".

I tried a few things, such as an OR `|` with the start of string character `^`. I also tried a look behind to check for `^` or `Correction`  but the error says they need to be constant length.

```
r"((^|Correction ).*?(?=DIVIDEND|\(All|CONS|COMM|Section))"
```

gives an error; `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`. I'm new to regex so I don't really know what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an optional part, and in instead of lookarounds use a capture group with a match:

```
^(?:Correction\s*)?(\S.*?)\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|DIVIDEND|All|CONS|COMM|Section)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:Correction\s*)?`
- `(\S.*?)\s*` Capture in **group 1**, matching a non whitespace char and as least chars as possible and match (not capture) 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(` till `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `DIVIDEND|All|CONS|COMM|Section` Match any of the words
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbtZaE/1)

```
data = ["Netflix DIVIDEND", "Apple Inc (All Sessions) COMM", "Intel Corporation CONS", "Correction Netflix Section 31 Fee"]
pattern = r"^(?:Correction\s*)?(\S.*?)\s*(?:\([^()]*\)|DIVIDEND|All|CONS|COMM|Section)"
transactions_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MarketName'])
transactions_df["Share Name"] = transactions_df["MarketName"].str.extract(pattern)
print(transactions_df)
```

Output

```
0                   Netflix DIVIDEND            Netflix
1      Apple Inc (All Sessions) COMM          Apple Inc
2             Intel Corporation CONS  Intel Corporation
3  Correction Netflix Section 31 Fee            Netflix
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Regex is confusing, I'll have to learn more about capture groups.